# Use Vue's directive to change Dom style but not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, directive

I'm trying to use Vue to build my app but I have a problem with image loading speed. I have written a directive to control it:

```
 <div   style="width:1280px;height:800px;background-size:100% 100%"                   imgload="product.bgImg  ">
    <div class="backgroud" style="display: block" title="p1">
         <div>{{product.productTitle}}</div>
          <img src=""   style="border-style:none" />
          <div  is="tip-compont" class="tips" v-bind:position="product.tips"></div>
          <template   v-for="r of product.rect">
              <div  is="rect-compont" shape="rect"  v-bind:position="r"  v-on:click="update()" ></div>
           </template>
           <template v-for="c of product.circle">
                <div is="circle-compont" shape="circle" v-bind:position="c"></div>
            </template>
           </div>
        </div>
Vue.directive('imgload',{inserted:function (el,binding,vnode,oldno) {
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=binding.value;
    var sty='url('+binding.value+') no-repeat';
    el.style.background=sty;
}})
```

But it doesn't seems to work. Images don't show on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append a **v-** in your HTML to use it as Vue directive, like following:

```
<div style="width:1280px;height:800px;background-size:100% 100%" v-imgload="product.bgImg">
...
```

You can check more details in [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments).

Comment: @G.Z.P If this solves your issue, you can mark it as correct answer and upvote it if you want to increase the credibility of the answer.